# How to fill data dynamically in Highchart

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I'm using below code to display bar chart, I don't know how to populate value dynamically in **name** and **y** field. I've name and y data in javascript array.

```
var productsName = [Laptop,Photoframe,PuzzleBox];
var productPrintCount = [56,24,10]
```

I don't want to hardcode name and y value in chart, I want to populate dynamically, can someone help how can I put these value in below chart?

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3jddkk0c/)

```
 data: [{
        name: 'Laptop',
        y: 56
    }, {
        name: 'Photoframe',
        y: 24
    }, {
        name: 'PuzzleBox',
        y: 10
    }]
```

Comment: So you mean that you have the data in two arrays, and you want to change the format so it's an array of objects as in the last example, is that right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var productsName = ['Laptop', 'Photoframe', 'PuzzleBox'],
    productPrintCount = [56,24,10],
    mappingDataFn = function () {
            var resultData = [];
            $.each(productsName, function (key, value) {
                resultData.push({
                    'name': value,
                    'y': productPrintCount[key]
            });
        });
        return resultData;
    };
...
    series: [{
        name: 'Brands',
        colorByPoint: true,
        data: mappingDataFn()
    }]
```

The idea:
mapping the data from a function.
here the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3jddkk0c/1/)